# Co-Turn server not working properly for Web RTC project

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

I have a turn server which is using co-turn and hosted on GCP.

And already installed the server successfully without any error and enabled the port.

But when I used it back on my web rtc project, it seems like it's not working because my application only works only on the same router or network.

It's not working on a different network.

I tried checking on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ and get the following result which says it is fine.

So, i'm a bit lost about where to check anymore.

Please kindly help me what I can check anywhere else. Thanks.

[image]

============================================

Updated after adding external IP.

[image]

### Latest Update

When I debug on chrome://webrtc-internals/, there is an error message on icecandidateerror event which state as Unauthorized.

```
url: turn:turn.xxxxx.live:5349?transport=udp
address: 10.19.95.x
port: 41207
host_candidate: 10.19.95.x:41207
error_text: Unauthorized
error_code: 401
```

When I recheck the turn server which I created with reference to [this link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1175/how-to-create-and-configure-your-own-stun-turn-server-with-coturn-in-ubuntu-18-04), I still have user=guest:somepassword line, so trying my server with that password to confirm if it is the user issue.

Still no luck though. Please help me guide where did I need to look more into.

Since I'm new to this technology and infrastructure, I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 5):

`10.138.0.2` probably isn't what you want. Edit the coturn config to set a `--external-ip` value that is the external IP of your TURN server. This page should print the world routable IP of your TURN server, not `10.138.0.2`

When you create a new PeerConnection are you sure you are passing the values properly? Can you confirm that `onicecandidate` emits `srflx` and `relay` candidates? This probably isn't the issue, but worth checking.

Comment: Hi @Sean, first of all, thanks for the answer. It is great to have some response.

Regarding the server, I added the --external-ip and the response is now changed. But the issue is still there.

Not really sure about that onicecandidate emitting srflx and relay thing. Can you please help to elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: Also, I can share with you my project link via PM if it might be helpful for you to help.

Comment: When `onicecandidate` is called do you send the candidate to the other PeerConnection and call `addIceCandidate` ? When `onicecandidate` is called you will see `host`, `srflx` or `relay`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/addIceCandidate is a good example

Comment: Hello Sean, I was using the following example for the group chat.
https://github.com/anoek/webrtc-group-chat-example

And yes, when I check on the onicecandidate event, it was sent the candidate information which is 

""candidate:1228400177 1 udp 2122260223 10.64.112.51 47863 typ host generation 0 ufrag UMrY network-id 1 network-cost 900"".  

Is 10.64.112.51 was the issue there? Looks likes it is sending out the local IP.

Comment: Did you add your TURN server config here https://github.com/anoek/webrtc-group-chat-example/blob/master/client.html#L31-L33 ? You can also look in `chrome://webrtc-internals` that has useful debugging info.

Comment: Yes. I add them in like below. 

 var ICE_SERVERS = [
     { url: "stun:stun.xxxxxxxx.live:5349" },
  {
     url: 'turn:turn.xxxxxxxx.live:5349',
     credential: 'xxxxxxxx',
     username: 'xxxxxxxx'
 }
 ];

I will check the chrome://webrtc-internals tools.

Comment: I found an interesting piece of information.

icecandidateerror
url: turn:turn.xxxxx.live:5349?transport=udp
address: 10.19.95.x
port: 43311
host_candidate: 10.19.95.x:43311
error_text: Unauthorized
error_code: 401..... 

I think I misconfigure the turn server access. I will look more into it. Please let me know if you have some great example as well.

Comment: I updated the question. Please check if you have some spare time. Thanks Sean.

Comment: And the same credentials work on the ICE trickle test page? It could possible be a browser cache issue? The trickle ICE page just creates a PeerConnection with those attributes, so really not sure what it could be!

Comment: Yes. Both credentials working fine on ICT trickle page. And I double-check the credentials on the web page javascripts. Everything looks correct. Can help me to check If I share you all the project?

Comment: Hello Sean, any other idea? I'm still stuck at this point.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any ideas, I am not that familiar with coturn. Maybe try deploying a different TURN server locally and testing with that. I work on this one https://github.com/pion/turn/tree/master/examples and we distribute static binaries for Windows/Mac/Linux so could be an easy way to test quickly!